# What should be the State Value in Pinterest?

Tags: pinterest

I need to set some extra parameters while OAuth but If I put it wont come after redirection from pinterest.In this case Shall i have state value as JSONString So that i can use multiple keys and able to retrieve those after redirecting into my callback url.

Answer (score 0):

The `state` parameter will be passed back to the redirect URI as is, so you should be able to use whatever serialization format you want for the extra data that you need preserved. Make sure that the `state` is properly URL-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jean says it can be anything. A good practice is to generate a random string every time your system needs to OAuth someone.

Since the state parameter is not an invention of Pinterest but a parameter often used for OAuth you may find plenty of reference implementations in your language. For JavaScript [Passport](http://passportjs.org) uses `uid(24)` based on the [uid2 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uid2).